# Importing from another file doesn't work in PyPI

Tags: python, import, module, package

I'm making a package in python, something like:

```
package/__init__.py  
package/A.py  
package/B.py
```

And I want to import a function from A to B. The obvious way is: `from A import function`
And this actually works, for me, because I uploaded this to PyPI and it doesn't work, it tells me 'No module named 'A'
And if I do `from package.A import function` it says  'No module named 'package'
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide your configuration (`setup.cfg` and/or `setup.py`)?

Comment: This is the [project](https://github.com/Bouchet07/intelligen), the error is in linregress.py when importing AI

Comment: try `from .AI import function`

Comment: This .AI works, thanks, but when I run it locally doesn't work, it says 'attempted relative import with no known parent package', how can I test it before uploading?